# Indoor chilis infected by strange problem

Tags: diseases, pests, chili

I am having problems with something affecting, infecting my Carolina reaper plants. I can see curled leaves, white blotches. With a microscope i see tiny “suckers.” Any ideas? [image]

Comment: some more pictures would help, the one you have posted is not very clear